# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, integer given in

Tags: php, mysqli

There are many posts relating to same question, But still the problem continues to remain, Sorry, please help me solving this.

```
    <?php

$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$dbase="cms";

$connection=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbase");
if($connection=mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Error estabilishing conection : ".mysqli_connect_error(). "(" .mysqli_connect_errno().")";
}

?>


<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM pages";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(!$result){
    die("Database query failed..");
}

?>
```

Comment: I wonder what the two files your includes do. Especially connection.php looks suspect. Does it maybe overwrite $connection ??

Comment: they both are 2 separate files.. above code itself in connection.php

Answer (score 3):

Line

```
if($connection=mysqli_connect_errno()){
```

assigns `mysqli_connect_errno()` to `$connection` variable.

This line should be replaced with:

```
if (!$connection) {
```

And full connection code is:

```
$connection=mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbase");
if(!$connection){
    echo "Error estabilishing conection : ".mysqli_connect_error(). "(" .mysqli_connect_errno().")";
}
```

Comment: @AlanMachado the comment was prior to update ;)

Comment: @AlanMachado NP, I've actually deleted the comment as it don't make sense anymore.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. I shouldn't have assigned $connection to mysqli_connect_errno.